# NGram on dataset with one word

Tags: apache-spark, nlp, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, n-gram

I'm dabbling with SparkML, trying to build out a fuzzy match using Spark's OOB capabilities. Along the way, I'm building NGrams with n=2. However, some lines in my dataset contains single words where Spark pipeline fails. Regardless of Spark, wondering what would be the general approach to this problem. ie. what if tokens

Comment: what if tokens ...

Comment: Can you comment on what has been presented as is the norm here at SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCALA approach. Normally it should work with 1 word as well and not fail, crash. Using non-MLLIB but sliding you get a bigram of 1 which is debatable of course, with sentence parsing. like this:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array("Hello my Friend. How are",
                               "you today? bye my friend.",
                               "singleword"))
rdd.map{ 
    // Split each line into substrings by periods
    _.split('.').map{ substrings =>
        // Trim substrings and then tokenize on spaces
        substrings.trim.split(' ').map{_.replaceAll("""\W""", "").toLowerCase()}.
        // Find bigrams, etc.
        sliding(2)
     }.
    // Flatten, and map the ngrams to concatenated strings
    flatMap{identity}.map{_.mkString(" ")}.
    // Group the bigrams and count their frequency
    groupBy{identity}.mapValues{_.size}
}.
// Reduce to get a global count, then collect.  
flatMap{identity}.reduceByKey(_+_).collect.
// Print
foreach{x=> println(x._1 + ", " + x._2)}
```

This does not fail on the "singleword" but gives you a single word:

```
you today, 1
hello my, 1
singleword, 1
my friend, 2
how are, 1
bye my, 1
today bye, 1
```

Using mllib and going over lines with this input:

```
the quick brown fox.
singleword.
two words.
```

using:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
val wordsRdd = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/sliding.txt",1)
val wordsRDDTextSplit = wordsRdd.map(line => (line.trim.split(" "))).flatMap(x => x).map(x => (x.toLowerCase())).map(x => x.replaceAll(",{1,}","")).map(x => x.replaceAll("!{1,}",".")).map(x => x.replaceAll("\\?{1,}",".")).map(x => x.replaceAll("\\.{1,}",".")).map(x => x.replaceAll("\\W+",".")).filter(_ != ".").filter(_ != "")
.map(x => x.replace(".","")).sliding(2).collect
```

you get:

```
 wordsRDDTextSplit: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(the, quick), Array(quick, brown), Array(brown, fox), Array(fox, singleword), Array(singleword, two), Array(two, words))
```

Note I parse the lines differenty.

When running the above with just one line with 1 word, then I get null output.

```
wordsRDDTextSplit: Array[Array[String]] = Array()
```

So, you see you can process over lines or not, etc.